# User space bridging - Linux vs. FreeBSD

Tags: linux, network-programming, debian, freebsd, pf-ring

### Background:

I'm working on porting a packet parsing/manipulation program from FreeBSD to Linux (specifically Debian - jessie). This program implements a bi-directional bridge between two physical interfaces while performing parsing/manipulation prior to TX operations.

In FreeBSD, this application used Pcap to RX/TX. In Linux, so far I've tested with Pcap, PACKET_MMAP (using TPACKET_V2) and Vanilla PF_RING.

### Test Results:

Using the same hardware and laboratory environment, I observed the following (approximate) throughput results from several tests performed with iperf:

- FreeBSD Kernel bridge: 880Mb/s
- FreeBSD Pcap (user space) bridge: 700Mb/s
- Debian Kernel bridge: 880Mb/s
- Debian Pcap (user space) bridge: 120Kb/s
- Debian Vanilla PF_RING (user space) bridge: 980Kb/s
- Debian PACKET_MMAP (user space) bridge: 480Kb/s

### Thoughts and Question:

The Debian user space speeds seem ridiculous to me. They're unusable - and I suspect I'm missing something. Is there a system option I need to enable ("go fast", lol)?

Or is this just how it is with Linux user space bridging?

### Edit / Update

I have a lingering suspicion that there's an administrative limitation affecting the Debian tests. I'm searching system documentation for (something / anything) to no avail. Any ideas on what could be limiting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obscure questions find obscure answers...

After much research I found the "problems" with Linux in this case is actually the result of optimizations. By default, apparently, the systems are optimizing for large sustained loads (so YMMV with the below "fix").

I resolved the speed issues and found the same throughput as the FreeBSD systems by using ethtool to adjust the optimizations on my two bridge interfaces:

```
ethtool -K eth1 gso off gro off tso off ufo off lro off
```

After the above on both interfaces, PF_RING and PACKET_MMAP met the Kernel bridge speed (which is the maximum speed for my test lab) and Pcap tests resulted in around 300Mb/s.

Comment: Hi @TrunkFullOfGoats, any chance you would share your code?  I'm trying to implement something similar on FreeBSD (or Linux, if that fails).  I'm trying to bridge two interfaces but filter out 802.1x packets in an effort to work around a vulnerable and crappy AT&T UVerse modem.  I'm basically trying to implement this, but on FreeBSD:  https://github.com/jaysoffian/eap_proxy/

It would be a huge help if I had some example code for bridging two interfaces in (Linux, FreeBSD) while parsing & manipulating packets.

Comment: Hey, sorry this response is extremely late. I cannot provide the source because the majority of it that's not open source is not owned by me. There's plenty of material available for writing a FBSD libpcap bridge though. You simply need to search for libpcap reading/writing. Here's a few links to start: https://github.com/google/packetdrill/blob/master/gtests/net/packetdrill/packet_socket_pcap.c and https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html. Hopefully that's helpful!